# Why is my NSURLConnection so slow?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, http-post

I have setup an NSURLConnection using the guidelines in [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) from the Mac OS X Reference Library, creating an NSMutableURLRequest as POST to a PHP script with a custom body to upload 20 MB of data (see code below).  Note that the post body is what it is (line breaks and all) to exactly match an existing desktop implementation.

When I run this in the iPhone simulator, the post is successful, but takes an order of magnitude longer than if I run the equivalent code locally on my Mac in C++ (20 minutes vs. 20 seconds, respectively).

Any ideas why the difference is so dramatic?  I understand that the simulator will give different results than the actual device, but I would expect at least similar results.

Thanks

```
const NSUInteger kDataSizePOST = 20971520;
const NSString* kUploadURL = @"http://WWW.SOMEURL.COM/php/test/upload.php";
const NSString* kUploadFilename = @"test.data";
const NSString* kUsername = @"testuser";
const NSString* kHostname = @"testhost";

srandom(time(NULL));
NSMutableData *uniqueData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:kDataSizePOST];
for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < kDataSizePOST ; ++i) {
    u_int32_t randomByte = ((random() % 95) + 32);
    [uniqueData appendBytes:(void*)&randomByte length:1];
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kUploadURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"aBcDd";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\nContent-Size:%d",boundary,[uniqueData length]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=test; filename=%@", kUploadFilename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@";\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:uniqueData]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\nContent-Size:%d",boundary,[kUsername length]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nContent-Disposition: inline; name=Username;\n\r\n%@",kUsername] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\nContent-Size:%d",boundary,[kHostname length]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nContent-Disposition: inline; name=Hostname;\n\r\n%@",kHostname] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n--%@--",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    _receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}

[request release];
[uniqueData release];
```

Comment: first of all run your code with profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there's a couple of things wrong here.

- You're generating 20MB of random data, this will take ages on an iOS device :)
- You're keeping this 20MB in memory, which is a little memory intensive on an iOS device. You'd be better off saving it to a file.
- You're also setting up the body manually which just isn't necessary. I'd recommend using [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and not even using NSData and using ASIFormDataRequest's addFile:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:

Comment: Good points, but this doesn't really answer the question about why the POST is so slow.  Once the data is created (however it is created), the actual post itself is crawling.  Is there something I am doing wrong that would explain that?  Also, as mentioned, I am setting up the body manually to exactly match an existing implementation.

Comment: Apart from the point where I tell exactly why it's slow, because you're generating 20Mb of random data on a slow device then manually copying that to another NSMutableData. Use files and ASIFormDataRequest.

Comment: Thanks. I was not intending to dismiss your input.  I was just assuming that was not the root cause because the time to get to the NSURLConnection initWithRequest is very fast.  The time after that (the post itself) is very slow.  I'll try your recommendation and see what happens.

Comment: I went ahead and set this as the accepted answer since the ASIHTTPRequest looks promising.  So far, I have not had a problem with generating 20 MB of random data and doing the work in memory.  It takes only a couple seconds while the user sees, "Preparing test..."